# Primary ideals in valuation rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ${\bf valuation}$ ${\bf ring}$ in the classical sense: $A$ is a domain with quotient field $K$ and for every non-zero $x\in K$ one has $x\in A$ or $x^{-1}\in A$.

Now ${\bf Bourbaki}$ (Commutative Algebra, Chapter VI, exercise 1 for §4) suggests that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is any non-maximal prime ideal of $A$, then $A$ does not possess any $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideals other than $\mathfrak{p}$ itself.

But $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ (cf. ${\bf Matsumura}$, Commutative ring theory, Theorem 10.1), which is the maximal ideal of $A_\mathfrak{p}$ (another valuation ring of $K$).
Hence $\mathfrak{p}^2$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-primary in $A_\mathfrak{p}$, and it follows that $\mathfrak{p}^2\cap A = \mathfrak{p}^2$ is $\mathfrak{p}\cap A$ - primary in $A$ - that is, $\mathfrak{p}$-primary.

And it is easy to find examples where $\mathfrak{p}^2 \ne \mathfrak{p}$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are Bourbaki and Matsumura working with the same definition of primary ideal? I know that, for non-Noetherian rings, there are at least 2 different definitions out there.

Comment: Yes, same definition: $\mathfrak{q}$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-primary in $A$ if $A/\mathfrak{q}$ is a non-zero ring in which every zero-divisor is nilpotent, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is the radical of $\mathfrak{q}$.

Comment: And $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ is easily seen. Take $x\in \mathfrak{p}$ and $s\in A-\mathfrak{p}$; then $s.x^{-1} \notin A$ (for else $s = (s.x^{-1}).x \in \mathfrak{p}$), so the inverse $x.s^{-1} \in A$ because $A$ is a valuation ring. As $(x.s^{-1}).s \in \mathfrak{p}$ and $s\notin \mathfrak{p}$, it follows that $x.s^{-1} \in \mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: And I'm considering the commutative case only.

Comment: In the special case where $\dim R = 1$, this is not surprising, because then a non-maximal prime ideal is $(0)$, which is identical to its square. Are you sure it is easy to find examples where $\mathfrak{p}^2\neq\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: All examples necessarily involve totally ordered abelian groups, and may therefore seem somewhat unwieldy. Cf. Atiyah and Macdonald, Intro to Comm. Algebra, chapter 6, exercises 30 - 33.

Let me present one example, based on the ordered group $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. It does not fit in the space allowed for a single comment, so I have spread it out over several ones.

Let $B = k[X,Y]$, $k$ a field. Order the monomials in $B$ lexicographically: $X^mY^n \leq X^uY^v$ iff $m \lt u$ or $(m = u$ and $n \leq v)$, for $m,n,u,v \geq 0$. So for example $XY^2 < X^2Y$ and $Y^7 < X$.


Comment: Put $K = k(X,Y)$, the quotient field, and let $A$ be the subring of the $F/G\in K$ that have $F = \alpha_1X^{m_1}Y^{n_1}+\ldots+\alpha_rX^{m_r}Y^{n_r}\in B$ and $G = \beta_1X^{u_1}Y^{v_1}+\ldots+\beta_sX^{u_s}Y^{v_s}\in B$, and the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j\in k$, and the monomials in ascending order: $X^{m_1}Y^{n_1} \lt X^{m_2}Y^{n_2} \ldots  \lt X^{m_r}Y^{n_r}$ and $X^{u_1}Y^{v_1} \lt X^{u_2}Y^{v_2} \ldots  \lt X^{u_s}Y^{v_s}$, and finally $X^{m_1}Y^{n_1} \geq X^{u_1}Y^{v_1}$.

Comment: $A$ is a valuation ring, because if not $X^{m_1}Y^{n_1} \geq X^{u_1}Y^{v_1}$ then $X^{m_1}Y^{n_1} \leq X^{u_1}Y^{v_1}$.

The set $\mathfrak{p}$ of those $F/G\in A$ as above with $m_1 \gt u_1$ is a prime ideal of $A$. (It is not $X.A$ for it also contains e.g. $XY^{-3}$ while $Y^{-3}\notin A$.) Then $\mathfrak{p}^2$ consists of the $F/G$ having $m_1 \gt u_1+1$. So e.g. $X$ is in $\mathfrak{p}$ but not in $\mathfrak{p}^2$.

Comment: One has dim$(A) = 2$, with the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_A$ consisting of the $F/G$ that satisfy $X^{m_1}Y^{n_1} \gt X^{u_1}Y^{v_1}$ (while the ones for which one has $X^{m_1}Y^{n_1} = X^{u_1}Y^{v_1}$ form the units of $A$).

Comment: Am I correct to think that in your example $A$ is not noetherian? For instance, I think $\mathfrak{p}$ is not a finitely generated ideal, is it?

Comment: Also, as far as I can see, Bourbaki defines primary ideals only for noetherian rings. Since in the exercise that you refer to, they speak of primary ideals, perhaps a noetherian condition is missing there? Otherwise how can they speak of a $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideal if the ring is not noetherian? On the other hand, will the exercise be trivial if a noetherian condition is added?

Comment: Mahdi, yes the above $A$ is not noetherian. In a valuation ring every finitely generated ideal is principal. So a noetherian valuation ring is a principal ideal domain, hence of dimension 1 (if it's not a field).

Comment: Bourbaki does not restrict primary ideals to noetherian rings. In the text, they treat primary decomposition only for noetherian rings. But in the exercises they discuss counterexamples in the non-noetherian case - valuation domains of dimension $\geq$ 2 being a case in point.

As always (and in any ring $A$), an ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-primary iff $A/\mathfrak{q}$ is a non-zero ring in which every zero-divisor is nilpotent, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is the radical of $\mathfrak{q}$.

Comment: Is it possible that part c) of the question should read: ``for a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ to be $\mathfrak{p}$ primary it is necessary and sufficient that it satisfy...''

Maybe this is i) non-trivial and ii) helpful for part d) of the question.

Comment: David, thanks for looking at the exercise. Its formulation is indeed somewhat unclear. It could be read as "if $H$ = {0} (so $\mathfrak{p}$ is a maximal ideal) any ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-primary", which is of course nonsense. I assume they mean that $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal overprime of $\mathfrak{q}$ (and hence its radical).

If $\mathfrak{q}$ itself is prime, it cannot be $\mathfrak{p}$-primary for any $\mathfrak{p}$ other than $\mathfrak{q}$. But that is trivial and true under any circumstances.

Comment: @Mahdi Is there a definition of primary ideals for noetherian rings and another one for non-noetherian rings?

Comment: @YACP Whether the formulation (of the exercise, if that's what you mean?) is clear or not, it is definitely NOT the case that primary ideals of valuation rings are prime whenever their radical is different from the maximal ideal. (And the value group of a valuation ring is always totally ordered.)

Comment: @Matthe Ok. I've read the whole topic and I've understood that the exercise in Bourbaki is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly valuation rings in which each non-maximal prime ideal has no primary ideal except itself.  Any Noetherian valuation ring has this property for trivial reasons.  Also, this is true for any valuation ring $R$ with value group of the form $G_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus G_n$ under lexicographic order, where each $G_i$ is a *non-discrete* (i.e. dense) subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$.

To see this, note that we can parametrize the entire prime spectrum of $R$ from looking at the value group. Indeed, the $\operatorname{Spec} R$ looks like $0 \subset \mathfrak p_1 \subset \mathfrak{p}_2 \subset \cdots \subset \mathfrak{p}_n$. To use the $G_i$, note that the nonzero elements of $\mathfrak p_1$ are the ones where the first coordinate of the value is positive; the elements of $\mathfrak p_2 \setminus \mathfrak p_1$ are those whose values' first coordinate is zero and second coordinate positive, those of $\mathfrak p_3 \setminus \mathfrak p_2$ have value with the first *two* coordinates $0$ and *third* coordinate positive, and so forth.  The fact that $\mathfrak p_i^2= \mathfrak p_i$ comes directly from the fact that $G_i$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

However, you are right, in that any non-Noetherian valuation domain with finite rank and *discrete* value group will fail this property.  That is, every nonzero non-maximal prime has nontrivial primary ideals.

Comment: Neil, thanks a lot! This is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Neil, I'm afraid to report that even in the example you present there exist non-trivial primary ideals to the non-zero non-maximal prime ideals:-)

Let us take value group $\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathfrak{p}$ = {the elements of the associated valuation ring having value $(x,y)$ with $x\gt0$} is, as you state, the only non-zero non-maximal prime ideal. Therefore it is the only minimal overprime (and hence the radical) of any non-zero ideal contained in it. You are right that $\mathfrak{p}$ = $\mathfrak{p}^2$, but still there exist $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideals other than $\mathfrak{p}$.

Indeed, consider $\mathfrak{q}$ = {elements having value $(u,v)$ with $u\geq$1}. Then $\mathfrak{q}$ is an ideal of $A$, and we have $\mathfrak{q}\subset\mathfrak{p}$. Hence $\surd\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{p}$ by the above. Now if $a$ and $b$ are in $A$ and $b\notin\mathfrak{p}$, the value of $b$ must be $(0,v)$ for some $v\in\mathbb{R}$ (with $v\geq0$). And if we also have $a\notin\mathfrak{q}$, and $(x,y)$ denotes $a$'s value, then necessarily $x \lt1$. And so the value of $ab$, being the sum $(x,y+v)$ of the values of $a$ and $b$, does not satisfy $x\geq1$, and therefore $ab\notin \mathfrak{q}$. This shows that $\mathfrak{q}$ is a primary ideal, and thus a $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideal $\neq\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Hm.  I suppose you are right.  I should have been more careful.

Well, here's at least an example of a valuation ring where there *exists* a non-maximal nonzero prime $\mathfrak p$ with no proper non-primary subideals.  Let's take a valuation ring with value group $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb Z$, with lex order.  That is, you have countably many copies of $\mathbb Z$ with order type $\mathbb N$, plus one at the end.  Then let $\mathfrak p$ be the ideal of elements whose value has some nonzero entry *before* the last entry.  Then $\mathfrak p$ is the union of ...

Comment: ... the prime ideals that it properly contains. Indeed, these primes can be parametrized by $\mathbb N$, such that $\mathfrak{p}_{i-1} \subset \mathfrak{p}_i$ and $\mathfrak{p}_i \setminus \mathfrak{p}_{i-1}$ are the elements with zeros in the first $i-1$ places and positive value in the $i$th place.  Clearly $\mathfrak{p} = \bigcup_i \mathfrak{p}_i$.  Now, suppose $\mathfrak q$ is a $\mathfrak p$-primary ideal. Then since it is not contained in any prime properly contained in $\mathfrak p$, it must contain all such primes, and hence it contains their union $\mathfrak p$. That is, $\frak q=p$.

Comment: You're welcome again.  I should say that the property you are asking about is called "branched".  A prime ideal $P$ in a commutative ring $R$ is called *branched* if there is some $P$-primary ideal properly contained in $P$; otherwise, it is *unbranched*.  So, for instance, in a Noetherian integral domain, $0$ is always the only unbranched prime ideal

Answer (score 0):

In the specific example set out in the above comments, $\mathfrak{p^2}$ is a $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideal of $A$ - in contradiction with the statement quoted from Bourbaki (still, after all, of course, a very authoriative source).

Comment: "Authoritative", I meant to say.